# Show membership for all naturals

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am pretty confused by the approach to consider (of course, except mathematical induction; that seems not correct for considering all cases possible) question as below. Mathl. induction fails, and I am not sure of using it.

Show that the numbers generated by the formula are all lying in the set of 
naturals, for n being a natural number:

$\frac{(3n)!}{3^n} \in N$

Comment: How about induction?

Comment: So you wonder why, say $$\frac{1\times2\times3\times4\times5\times6\times7\times8\times9\times10\times11\times12}{3\times3\times3\times3}\in\Bbb N?$$ Can you do any cancelling?

Comment: Why do you state that mathematical induction fails? Hint: it doesn't.

Comment: It failed in classic cases (in history!), and am not sure of what difference the strong form will bring (if it were to fail for simpler form of induction). If the strong form guarantees something, please show or refer - particularly for classic cases (historical).

Comment: @jiten My feeling is that said failures of mathematical induction are, nowadays, to be considered human mistakes, rather than issues of the procedure itself. Can you name three?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I am not able to remember three, but one I can gather now; and even then I would say that application of induction to that would fail. It is the Fermat’s conjecture about primes, i.e. $2^{2^n}$ + 1 being a prime. By induction, you are bound to fail, as few initial cases would pass the test.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I can do the cancelling, but will I need induction to prove this generally, that the factors will cancel out from the denominator completely.

Comment: @jiten Ah, in that sense. Induction is a perfectly viable strategy of solution for this problem, perhaps the most elementary one.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I need elaboration to clear my doubt that if few initial cases wrongly prove the correctness, then induction is a failure.

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about. There are no cases, be them small or large, where $3^n$ does not divide $(3n)!$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\prod_{r=1}^{3n}r=\prod_{m=1}^n(3m-2)(3m-1)(3m)=3^n\prod_{m=1}^nm(3m-2)(3m-1)$$

Comment: I am somewhat clear about your formula, but not totally. May be need more elaboration in the change of base and then taking only 3 terms in the product; or reference to some source. But, your formula totally proves the case, if understood.